# Problem installing plugin via path repository

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, composer

I am starting to play with writing a plugin in Craft 3.0. I have followed the following [page](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/plugin-intro.md). I used [Plugin Factory](https://pluginfactory.io/) to create my plugin structure (very nice). My folder structure is as follows:

```
/craft
/craft/vendor/recoveryfinder/nav
```

I uploaded the files and folders created bt the pluginfactury to /craft/vendor/recoveryfinder/nav folder. My additions to the craft project composer.json look like this:

After:

```
{
  "name": "craftcms/craft",
  "description": "Craft CMS",
```

I added:

```
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
```

After:

```
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
      "@composer dump-autoload -o",
      "@php craft setup/welcome"
    ]
  },
```

I added:

```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "./vendor/recoveryfinder/nav"
    }
  ]
```

I went to the terminal logged in as the user that owns the files and change location to:

> /craft

I then ran:

> composer require recoveryfinder/nav

The output I am getting is:

```
Using version ^0.9.0 for recoveryfinder/nav
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals


  [RuntimeException]
  Package recoveryfinder/nav cannot install to "/home/recoveryfinder/craft/vendor/recoveryfinder/nav" inside its source at "/home/recoveryfinder/craft/
  vendor/recoveryfinder/nav"


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I have not modified in any way the files created by pluginfactory.io.

Any pointers as to what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article I wrote [So You Wanna Make a Craft 3 Plugin?](https://nystudio107.com/blog/so-you-wanna-make-a-craft-3-plugin) may help you in terms of figuring out how to properly set up a "host" website to run your plugin development from.

TL;DR your repo shouldn't point to your site's vendor directory, it should point to wherever that plugin exists on your local dev environment.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was all messed up in where I was putting files. You are correct. The plug in files should exist outside of craft and then composer  sets things up in vendor.

Answer (score 2):

The composer adds all necessary files into the vendor directory. You should never implement files there on your own so you should create a `plugins` folder next to your vendor folder and insert the files there. Your path parameter will then be `/plugins/recoveryfinder/nav`